# How to get client certificates through identity server 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, certificate, smartcard, identityserver4

I am trying to build authentication system through ASP.NET MVC. I am using Identity Server 4 for authentication. I have already implemented user id and password validation through ResourceOwner.
Now I am trying to implement smart card authentication. When I try to read X509Certificate2 in debug mode, I am able to read the client certificates but when I deploy the application to IIS, I am unable to read the certificate.
I want to accept client certificate on my Identity Server hosted on IIS when request is sent to Identity Server 4 from client ASP.NET MVC. My Identity Server 4 project type is .NET Core on .NET Framework.

I have already tried this:

1. Installed authorized SSL certificate on IIS
2. Added HTTPS binding to my identity server 4 app pool with valid port number.
3. Enable SSL for the identity server site and set to accept client certificate.

Comment: When running on IIS you have IIS in the role of reverse proxy and Idsrv4 is behind it running in kestrel. Https is terminated at IIS so you can not find the certificate in connection.

Comment: I have tried to get certificate through kestrel and yes, I am unable to get.

Comment: when I write below code, it works for me in debug mode but not when hosted on IIS 
`X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);`

Now if I check store.Certificates, I can get list of certificate in debug mode but unable to get it on IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the client certificate in Identity Server 4 as below but it was without private key :

`var clientX509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(this.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate);`